# The problem with producing the colour in one of the column of the table produced by the formattable package

Tags: r, formattable, aesthetics

I applied this code earlier and the results were not totally upto the expectations as the matching_probability section did not show the colour tiles.
I couldn't add the image otherwise I would have shown.

```
formattable(df, 
            align = c("l","c","c","c","c","c","r"), 
            list(`Locus_number` = formatter(
                "span", style = ~ style(color = "grey",font.weight = "bold")), 
                `PIC`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
                `Matchin_Probability`= color_tile('white', 'orange'),
                `Power_of_Discrimination`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
                `Power_of_Exclusion`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
                `Paternity_Index` = color_bar(customRed)
            ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Had the same issue in the past , probably you have some inf values in the specific column just replace it with 0 or NA

```
df[mapply(is.infinite, df)] <- NA
```

Comment: can you add the data.frame it looks like one of the values is incorrect

Comment: I found the problem I mentioned the name of one of my Variable wrong that is why it was not compiling only that column.